# How to get the result of data from sql by month and divided into weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've created a script that getting a total of sales in the month that's declared by the user and grouping in weekly. But the problem is the total is exceeding in my declared date range. Because the month declared is not dividend in 7(This is the number of days in a week). And now I want to get the result based only in my date range.

this is my example query:

```
Set @starttime = '2014-10-01'
Set @endtime = '2014-10-31'

while @endtime > @starttime
begin
    print @starttime
    set @xendtime = DATEADD(DAY, 7,@starttime)

    print @xendtime
    set @starttime = DATEADD(DAY, 7,@starttime) 
end
```

And this is the result

```
Oct  1 2014 12:00AM ---@StartDate
Oct  7 2014 12:00AM ---@xEndDate
Oct  8 2014 12:00AM ---@StartDate
Oct 14 2014 12:00AM ---@xEndDate
Oct 15 2014 12:00AM ---@StartDate
Oct 21 2014 12:00AM ---@xEndDate
Oct 22 2014 12:00AM ---@StartDate
Oct 28 2014 12:00AM ---@xEndDate
Oct 29 2014 12:00AM ---@StartDate
Nov  4 2014 12:00AM ---@xEndDate <----- I want this to end in Oct 31.
```

Can you Help me with this? Please

Comment: What's the definition of a week? ISO week number or something else? Because [`DatePart(wk, @date)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) might work for you.

Comment: it is already dividing in week. but as you can see my Declared enddate is only Oct 31 2014. but Oct 29-Oct31 is anly 3 days. so the query must print a complete 7 days thats why it is exceeding until Nov 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your desired result with little amendments in your query.

```
declare @starttime datetime
```

`declare @endtime datetime
declare @time datetime
Set @starttime = '2014-10-01'
Set @endtime = '2014-10-31'`

`while @endtime > @starttime
begin
    print @starttime
    set @time = DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime)
    If @time<@endtime
    Begin
        print @time
        set @starttime = DATEADD(DAY, 1,@time) 
    End
    Else
    begin
        print @endtime
        set @endtime = @starttime
    End
end`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(Month(@xendtime) = month(@endtime))
    begin
    print @xendtime
    end
    else
    begin
    print @endtime
    end
```

Complete Query:

```
declare @starttime date
declare @endtime date
declare @xendtime date

Set @starttime = '2014-10-01'
Set @endtime = '2014-10-31'

while @endtime>@starttime
begin
    print @starttime
    set @xendtime = DATEADD(DAY, 7,@starttime)
   set @starttime = DATEADD(DAY, 7,@starttime)
if(Month(@xendtime) = month(@endtime))
    begin
    print @xendtime
    end
    else
    begin
    print @endtime
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DATEPART` like:

```
DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 7,@starttime))
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this works

```
  DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
    SELECT @startDate = '2014-10-01', @endDate = '2014-10-31'
    ;WITH DateCalendar AS (
        SELECT @startDate AS dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dt + 1 FROM DateCalendar
        WHERE dt + 1 <= @endDate
    )
    SELECT 
     NameMonth = DATENAME(Month, dt)
    ,NameDay = convert(varchar(20),dt,100)
    FROM DateCalendar
    WHERE DATENAME (Weekday,dt) IN ('Sunday','Saturday')
    Option(MaxRecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @starttime date
,@endtime date
,@xendtime date

Set @starttime = '2014-10-01'
Set @endtime = '2014-10-31'


while @endtime > @starttime
begin
    set @xendtime = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime) >= @endtime THEN @endtime ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime) END
    SELECT @starttime, @xendtime

    set @starttime = DATEADD(DAY, 1,@xendtime)
end
GO
```

Using CTE:

```
DECLARE @starttime date
,@endtime date
,@xendtime date

Set @starttime = '2014-10-01'
Set @endtime = '2014-10-31'

;WITH dt as (
SELECT @starttime as StartDate , CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime) >= @endtime THEN @endtime ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 6,@starttime) END EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1,dt.EndDate), CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7,dt.EndDate) >= @endtime THEN @endtime ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7,dt.EndDate) END
FROM dt
WHERE dt.EndDate < @endtime
)

SELECT *
FROM dt
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```